# Unused local variables in solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, blockchain, solidity-0.8.x

I am new in solidity and trying to run simple program in "remix ide" but right now i am getting following error

```
warning : unused local variables
uint a =1;
```

Here is my current code,Where i am wrong ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract SimpleStorage {
    constructor() public{
   }
    uint storedData;
    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }
    function get() public view returns (uint) {
        uint a = 1;
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a warning, not an error. That's not a problem, your contract can still run as normal. But you have a variable that you never use and is recommended to remove it.

Remove the line:

```
uint a = 1;
```

if you don't need it.

Also, I recommend you to upgrade to a newer solidity version like `^0.8.16` which has more features and more safe. But if you are just trying out different versions to see the difference, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

That's a warning, not an error.

It means that you define a variable which is not being read or written anywhere after the definition, means the variable is useless.